# What is different between Magento 2.3.5-p1 and 2.3.5 version?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I upgraded Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5. But Magento site https://magento.com/tech-resources/download is available version 2.3.5-p1? Something different with versions 2.3.5 and 2.3.5-p1? I want to know that is there any difference between both versions which one I need to update on the store ?

Comment: you've accepted the wrong answer, fyi

Comment: it's not wrong ... its correct ... if u have any more details or more specific answer then please add here so it will help to someone

Comment: See the comment I added to the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p1 suffix denotes the full release for the quarterly update and contains further fixes to a unique error. Generally if you're not experiencing errors I don't think you need to upgrade to p1, though I would take a look at p2 as this update is security related;

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-5-open-source.html

Answer (score 0):

A while ago Magento changed their release process to include security-only releases (https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Introducing-the-New-Security-only-Patch-Release/ba-p/141287?_ga=2.215616274.442714052.1591948834-51687988.1567676784). The version `2.3.5-p1` should be one such release.

For security issues, these are highlighted on the Adobe Security Bulletin and it seems for this patch we are looking at https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb20-22.html and you can see the vulnerability details at https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb20-22.html#Vulnerabilitydetails

Using github you can do a compare of the two tags `2.3.5` and `2.3.5-p1` https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.3.5...2.3.5-p1

With this overview you can see that there is only one commit difference between the two versions (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/13c18d0b3f2e3fa53b317db5452eaab3d28dbeca).

Comment: This is incorrect. From the magento website: "During pre-release, we discovered issues that forced us to create new packages. To expedite delivery, we chose to change the name of the full-release patch from 2.3.5 to 2.3.5-p1. The 2.3.5-p1 package contains all new features and fixes. We also changed the name of the security-only patch for this quarter from 2.3.4-p1 to 2.3.4-p2. Future releases will follow the typical package naming conventions for full-release and security packages."